# How to use Apache Camel exchange messages?

Tags: apache-camel

I am newcomer in Apache Camel. Please have a look to my code bellow:

I have a service which exposed as cxf webservice:

```
interface CxfService{
    public OutputType hello(InputType input);
}
```

This is my route:

```
from("cxf:/test?serviceClass=" + CxfService.class.getName())
    .to("log:cxfLog1")
    .recipientList(simple("direct:${header.operationName}"));

from("direct:hello")
    .process(new Processor(){

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            InputType file = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputType.class);
            exchange.getOut().setBody(new OutputType());
        }

    });
```

The code works as expected, it consume InputType and produce OutputType.

I want to borrow my body to do another stuffs, so i rewrite that like this:

```
from("cxf:/test?serviceClass=" + CxfService.class.getName())
    .to("log:cxfLog1")
    .recipientList(simple("direct:${header.operationName}"));

from("direct:hello")
    .process(new Processor(){

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            InputType file = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputType.class);
            exchange.getOut().setHeader("header.temporary", new OutputType());
        }

    })
    .to("some endpoint")
    .setBody(simple("${header.temporary}"));
```

This webservice consume InputType and produce nothing. What wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second piece of code, when setting the header.temporary, you should change two things:

1. `setHeader("temporary", new OutputType())` - the 'header' prefix isn't
   needed - you're addressing headers directly via the method call.
2. Use `getIn()` instead of `getOut()`. The input will get copied to the
   output. You may want to do some research into the procedure for
   Camel building the out message for details - I'm not 100% sure of
   this one.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader("header.temporary", new OutputType());
```

To

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("temporary"), new OutputType());
```

.setHeader() is when you use the simple language. In 99% of the cases getIn() is sufficient.